# Audit table design suggestions

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010, audit-trail, changelog

Is it the correct approach? Any suggestions to make it better?

1. Below is screenshot of employee table and its shadow table where the `tl_name` and `dept` fields may change and currently using shadow table to track all changes.
2. Records are inserted/updated in Main table and it gets copied to shadow table with help of data macro.
3. all the records in the shadow table have to be approved/rejected by superuser
4. Main table will have updated alignment and shadow table will have entire history of changes for any employee.
5. When a record is added/updated in Main table via userform, a copy of record will be created in shadow table which has to be approved by admin.
6. When a record is added/updated in Main table via userform, `is_active` field will be set as false and once it is approved by admin this will be updated to true.

[image]

Comment: What level of normalization are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just curious: why would anyone want to approve audit logs? if you want to prevent, you should prevent the user from editing the main table.
The laziest way to audit a table is to use table triggers. An Audit table has all field + Action, action by, action date. Use before and after update event to capture the entire row.

Comment: @krishKM  All changes have to be approved by Superuser as everyone have access to edit alignments self ( Its a business requirement). Currently I am using table triggers  (before change, after update) to caputre entire row.

Comment: I don't understand your business logic. *Everyone can edit the main table* and *All changes have to be approved* seems like a strange combination. What happens if a change is rejected?

Comment: @Andre All users have access to add new & update the employee list (Main table) so to prevent garbage all changes have to be approved. When changes are rejected, `is_rejected` is set to true in shadow table along with datestamp and userid, however `is_active` remains false in Main table. By default when data is inserted or updated `is_active` in Main table is set as false.

Comment: Oh. This is even more confusing. Are Main records with `is_active = False` visible to anyone? If yes, what is the significance of that flag? If no, do you have multiple records in Main for one employee? Otherwise they would disappear between being edited and approved.

Comment: can you update your question with screenshots of your views? are you using datasheet or form view? what is your current security level? users allowed to see the changes before gets approved? or do you want to show only after approved?

Comment: @krishKM I am yet to create form, but it will have the fields from main table.

Comment: users allowed to see the changes before gets approved? or do you want to show only after approved?

Comment: @Andre It would be visible to everyone in form view and they will know that it has to be approved.  'Emp ID' field is unique in main table and that's incorrect in the screenshot.

Comment: So a rejected change would stay visible forever with the changed data and `is_active = False`? That can't be right. I have the feeling this is not really thought through. -- Please update the screenshot with correct data to avoid confusion, thanks.

Comment: @Andre have updated the question, see if that makes sense. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Santosh These are not MS Access screenshots, they are from Excel and probably your idea of the end product in Access. Which clearly indicates you have an incomplete or missing business logic to build the system! Any approach is a valid one if you don't have a specific business logic. Including your current approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your requirements:

- Changed/inserted data should be immediately visible to everyone, with a visible flag for un-approved data.
- This is reasonable, if you work under the assumption that the majority of changes are correct and will be approved (hopefully true ;) ).

I think you are missing:

- If a change is rejected, the data in Main table should be automatically reverted to the most recent approved state.
- Otherwise the Main table stays in a (sort of) undefined state forever, with `is_active = False` and (apparently) wrong data.

This can be done with your audit table design. Find the latest approved entry for this emp PK, and use its data.

But if the number of columns that are audited may change in the future, you might consider an approach with two tables, as in this project: https://autoaudit.codeplex.com/documentation

> **AuditHeader** Table
>
> This table is inserted with one row everytime one record is inserted,
>   updated or deleted in a table that has been setup to use the AutoAudit
>   system.
>
> **AuditDetail** Table
>
> This table is related to AuditHeader and is inserted with one row for
>   each column that is changed during an insert or update operation and
>   for each column during a delete operation.

If you save old + new values with every change, you can revert to "old" state just from the current Audit entry.

And a structure change of Main table (or if you decide that e.g. users can edit `emp_name` too) doesn't need a structure change of the Audit table, because every audited column in Main is mapped to a row in AuditDetails instead of a column.

Edit: Additional advantage:

In your sample data you have marked the changed values in red. Obviously an Access table doesn't work like that. If you want to keep this information ("which column(s) exactly was edited?"), you would need an additional column in the Audit table.

This would be covered by AuditDetail, since it contains each change with old + new value.

Comment: @Santosh: What exactly did you expect from your question?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion...way to go!